# HTTP GET request result into array

Tags: flutter, dart

so i have this http req payload, and i want to push it into an array, can someone help me?

**The payload**

```json
{
   "status":200,
   "length":3,
   "results":[
      {
         "_id":"60cd70b3fb9fe400117e8c6b",
         "title":"Welcome to xxx",
         "body":"Welcome to xx! We’re excited that everyone’s here and hope your ready for an epic weekend."
      },
      {
         "_id":"60cd70b3fb9fe400117e8c6c",
         "title":"Lunch Info",
         "body":"Lunch is from our generous sponsors Lorem Ipsum! It will be served in the left atrium under the palm trees."
      },
      {
         "_id":"60cd70b3fb9fe400117e8c6d",
         "title":"Leash Dogs",
         "body":"A friendly reminder that dogs must be leashed at all times, no matter how cute <3"
      }
   ]
}
```

**My Provider Code [UPDATED]**

//So I've tried to debug on my own, and number 1 and number 2 is printed, while number 3 is not. I suspect its because of the way I handle extractedData.

```dart
 class Announcements {
  int? status;
  int? length;
  List<Results>? results;

  Announcements(
      {required this.status, required this.length, required this.results});

  Announcements.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    length = json['length'];
    if (json['results'] != null) {
      results = [];
      json['results'].forEach((v) {
        results!.add(new Results.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['status'] = this.status;
    data['length'] = this.length;
    if (this.results != null) {
      data['results'] = this.results!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}
// so i've used your online converter json
class Results {
  String? sId;
  String? title;
  String? body;

  Results({required this.sId, required this.title, required this.body});

  Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    sId = json['_id'];
    title = json['title'];
    body = json['body'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['_id'] = this.sId;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['body'] = this.body;
    return data;
  }
}

class AnnouncementProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  AnnouncementProvider(String? token, items);
  List _items = [];
  List get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  // List<Announcements> parseAnnouncement(String responseBody) {

  // }

  Future<List<Announcements>> fetchAnnouncements(String authToken) async {
    //var url = Uri.https('api-staging.xxx.us.org', '/1.0/announcements');
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://api-staging.xxx.us.org/1.0/announcements'),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $authToken',
      },
    );
    print(response.body);
    final t = Announcements.fromJson(response.body as Map<String, dynamic>);
    print(t.results);
    return t.results;
  }
}
```

What I need to know is, how do I return the list correctly, since the print(t.results) is actually not printed for some reason, so now it only shows "An error has occured" in my interface.
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you please add `print('4');` after `if (extractedData == null) { return; }` in order to ensure `extractedData != null` and report if it gets printed or not?

Comment: @purple okay, i'll try it

Comment: @purple its not printed, also if (extractedData == null) has this message:
The operand can't be null, so the condition is always false.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making a Dart Model object for the same, I would highly recommend you to do so because this is guaranteed serialization and type safe

For your case I used an imaginary name `FoodItems` for the type of data you received from your api endpoint

```
class FoodItems {
  int status;
  int length;
  List<Results> results;

  FoodItems({this.status, this.length, this.results});

  FoodItems.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    length = json['length'];
    if (json['results'] != null) {
      results = new List<Results>();
      json['results'].forEach((v) {
        results.add(new Results.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['status'] = this.status;
    data['length'] = this.length;
    if (this.results != null) {
      data['results'] = this.results.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Results {
  String sId;
  String title;
  String body;

  Results({this.sId, this.title, this.body});

  Results.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    sId = json['_id'];
    title = json['title'];
    body = json['body'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['_id'] = this.sId;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['body'] = this.body;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Now you can easily cast your `response.body` to the `FoodItems` class using `fromJson` method and then get the desired list of `Results` and then iterate over it
In my honest opinion, it makes it much simpler this way

**Note: I would highly recommend reading the following**

- [This](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) is a nice article from the Flutter Developers themselves
- [Android Studio Plugin to do the serialization for you](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12562-jsontodart-json-to-dart-)
- [Online converter](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)

Comment: i was hoping for the simple change in the codebase, but this solution might be cleaner, thank you!

Comment: Hello, may I have more explanation on "using fromJson method and then get the desired list of Results and then iterate over it"? 
 I've used your online converter tools, and I'll update the code in the question @gtxtreme

Comment: Hey @EdwardTanoto , when you get a model `Announcements` object using `fromJson` method, you can access the list of `Results` using results as you have done and try printing it properly

Comment: Also I would recommend you to use `jsonDecode` method available in flutter
If your `response.body` is a valid json then `jsonDecode` can do the job for you 

Replace 
`final t = Announcements.fromJson(response.body as Map<String, dynamic>`

To

`final t = Announcements.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)`

**Ensure that it is a valid json**